# React Native Expo Project: TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a pure Expo project and started developing and the error **TypeError: Network request failed** on both physical devices (iOS and Android).

I am calling an https API

```
function urlForQueryAndPage (key, value, pageNumber) {
const data = {
country: 'uk',
pretty: '1',
encoding: 'json',
listing_type: 'buy',
action: 'search_listings',
page: pageNumber,
};
data[key] = value;
const querystring = Object.keys (data)
.map (key => key + '=' + encodeURIComponent (data[key]))
.join ('&');
return 'https://api.nestoria.cok.uk/api?' + querystring;
}
```

I know that iOS blocks http calls, but I am calling an https API. Also I have the same error on Android and iOS immediately (no loading). I suppose there is some configuration that I have to do to allow network requests but I don't know how for an Expo project (I don't have an android/ios folder).

Both devices are connected via USB and Wifi (have internet connection). The App reload /Live Reload works perfectly.

Comment: are you use letsencrypt in server with nginx

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with that but I am not using it

Comment: Which version of Android do you have installed on your device? Which version of react native is used in your project? (npm list in your project)

Have you seen this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5222